# Storing passwords on NodeJS configuration

Tags: node.js, encryption, configuration

In .NET every application has its own app.config or web.config file where we can store our configuration, I'm looking for something equivalent for NodeJS, I understand it would be very easy to create a config.json file and just require it but the challenge comes in the fact that some of my configuration is actually a password I want have encrypted.

I was wondering if NodeJS has any tools equivalent to apsnet_regiis.exe which can be used to encrypt the whole configuration or sections of it and if not, what are the best practices in node to protect passwords and keys required by the application.

https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/877258/How-to-Encrypt-Web-config-Using-aspnet-regiis-exe

Answer (score 0):

You can use .env

Put this into your main js file

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv') // .env file
dotenv.config() // using .env
```

To install it, npm install dotenv

Then in your root folder, create file .env

You can put your sensitive info in the .env file

eg of .env file:

```
PORT = 3000
COOKIESECRET = 'yourSecretHere'
COOKIENAME = 'cookie'
```

TO use these settings, you use process.env.PORT to access that variable.

eg:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT
```

It will then access that file .env, find PORT, and take that data.

Additional information:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Some people advocate against plain text storage on the config files though, is there anything standard for safely encrypting the password? https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Password_Plaintext_Storage

Comment: @EduardoWada It's for your environment variables. Its stored separately from your codebase. If you want to store passwords, you encrypt it and save it to your database as per normal. Or you can use .env and store the Hash of your password, and you decrypt your hash to get your password. That will work too as I've done that before. But your password will be stored in your db.